# How to run demo files in angular-ui-bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am doing changes into one of the directives of Angular bootstrap (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) and I would like to see how the changes look.

I have seen there are demo files like:

\bootstrap\src\datepicker\docs\demo.html

But if I run http-server inside it or from the root folder and browser to that file, it doesn't work (component doesn't load)

I checked gruntfile.js file and found that after successful tests then \bootstrap\misc\demo folder is created so I also tried to run http-server from demo, misc and root, browsing them to index.html but none of them worked.

I also have checked README.md and CONTRIBUTING.md with no results.

What is the proper way to see changes done over directives of this library?

Comment: what error messages are you seeing in the browser console?

Comment: plunker.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
app.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

I think that this demo files are intended to be used in the plunker plugin that can be seen here: 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer: go to the base directory and run grunt. It will build the demos into /dist, which you can cd into and Then run http-server. If you made changes to anything in the datepicker.js file or the demo files for the datepicker, you'll see it in localhost. They use the actual Angular-UI docs page for the demo, so ctrl+F datepicker to jump to it and play around as you see fit.

It's worth mentioning twice that any changes you make to the demo files in /src/datepicker/docs will be used in that demo page in /dist.